# trigger function when retargeting object is created

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have implemented this plugin https://retargeting.biz/plugins/custom in my laravel app and I have some issues not with the plugin ...

The scripts that sits on the header ... when the page is loaded it created an object _ra and the functions that needs to exectute it only when

```
_ra.ready !== undefined
```

The problem is with the functions that I need to execute only when the page is loaded and send the data - because the script only run once. For the functions that need to be trriggered on a action (button, etc...) it's not a problem.

For example this script need to be loaded when the user enter on a category page.

```
function send_category() {
    var _ra = _ra || {};

    _ra.sendCategoryInfo = {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Shoes",
        "url": 'url_to_the_page',
        "parent": false,
        "breadcrumb": [] 
    };

    if (_ra.ready !== undefined) {
        _ra.sendCategory(_ra.sendCategoryInfo);
    }
}
```

What I did is:

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    send_category();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        send_category();
    })
}
```

but still... sometimes

```
_ra.ready = undefined
```

because the function runs and the object _ra in not yet created and the function is not executed (_ra.sendCategory)

What would you do it, in this case ?

I was thinking to use this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  send_category();
});
```

but what I know load event will do it when all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

Does this event "load" ... wait until the _ra object is created ???

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  send_category();
});
```

seems to work.